# Unable to retrieve Java Mongodb 2d index latitude and logtitude

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
DBCollection collection;
public static void main(String[] args) {
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost" , 27017 );
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("dispatch_location");
DBCollection collection=  db.getCollection("locale");
BasicDBObject point = new BasicDBObject();
collection.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("loc", "2d") );

new QueryBuilder ().near(-88.769896, 34.268103);
QueryBuilder  query = QueryBuilder.start();
    collection.findOne(query);
System.out.println(query);
```

I was getting null pointer excepton and a colleague told me to initialize DBCollection and I dont know how to initialize

Comment: Can you add the stack trace for the exception ?

Comment: Issue fixed in another way, thank you